# How can I switch language in google play?

Tags: google-play

I'm doing some statistical analysis about Google Play, comparing different languages. Every time I visit the site (http://play.google.com/store), it always opens in my language. I want to change the language displayed on the page, and also change the apps shown to a different country's market.
Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: The Play store recently changed (in my country at least)... I have almost the same question now http://stackoverflow.com/q/17672220/1093872

Comment: Solution exist, go here: https://www.google.com/settings/account  and in the Language section change your primary language.

Comment: check my answer in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/q/17672220/1093872

Comment: At least it displays in _your_ language. For me, it displays in whatever language Google thinks is the right one for my location. So if you live in a multi-language country, you better know the language Google decided on. And if travelling ...

Comment: What's even worse, for Germany, most app descriptions won't be in German but in Google-Translated-German which is the most unintelligible language of all.

Comment: What happened to "website honors the users language preference" ? Most OSes send the language preference set in general OS settings in HTTP request and should work correctly (as in: indicate the correct language that the user expects) 99% of cases. Now whenever people travel, they have to waste time googling (of course in foreign language) how to fix the language on each web site they visit.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Answer below the dotted line below is the original that's now outdated.

Here is the latest information ( Thank you @deadfish ):

add `&hl=<language>` like `&hl=pl` or `&hl=en`

example: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.xxx&hl=en or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.xxx&hl=pl

All available languages and abbreviations can be looked up here:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/4419860?hl=en

......................................................................

To change the actual local market:

Basically the market is determined automatically based on your IP. You can change some local country settings from your Gmail account settings but still IP of the country you're browsing from is more important. To go around it you'd have to Proxy-cheat. Check out some ways/sites:
http://www.affilorama.com/forum/market-research/how-to-change-country-search-settings-in-google-t4160.html

To do it from an Android phone you'd need to find an app. I don't have my Droid anymore but give this a try:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=694720

Comment: It doesn't work. It only can set page language, but I want change different country market.

Comment: You should've asked it to begin with. I updated my answer above.

Comment: this information is not up-to-date anymore, as google play has been updated and the dropdown menu has been removed

Comment: Example to set language Russian:
https://play.google.com/store?hl=ru

Comment: This is no longer available after the recent google play redesign

Comment: add `&hl=<language>` like `&hl=pl` or `&hl=en` example: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.xxx&hl=en` or `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.xxx&hl=pl` Now you can see comments

Comment: @deadfish Please post your simple solution as an answer.

Comment: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?hl=en

Comment: The answer is now updated

Comment: For me this is working: https://play.google.com/store?hl=tr or https://play.google.com/store?hl=en

Comment: Doesn't work, it just removes this parameter. (at least for the main page)

Comment: @MoreFreeze @Shenaniganz `https://play.google.com/store/movies?gl=us` the `gl=??` changes the market. `hl` changes the language.

Comment: is there any source we can get list of all the languages short code?

Comment: Check this below link to get the Google Play Store supported languages and short code
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/4419860?hl=en

Comment: why hl=az   uses hl=ru  language?

Comment: @KamilIbadov because there is no "az" I assume. Please see the list provided by Sujewan above

Comment: @InspiredBy it's solved by google play