# How to set language in the recently updated playstore?

Tags: google-play

The playstore in my country is updated today or yesterday and the language select option in the bottom of the page is no longer available.
My question is how read comments for a different language? (hopefully without using an unsecure proxy)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok I found a solution: add the hl=[language-code] parameter to the url:
ie.:

- https://play.google.com/store?hl=en
- https://play.google.com/store?hl=hu
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.adamtoth.pixelships&hl=en

Comment: Part of the page still features localized content. I am able to use hl=en but that gives me what I was already seeing. hl=fi gives me finnish content for what was already in english, but does not change content that seems to be determined by my location in the globe.

Comment: Then maybe try using a proxy from a different country.

Comment: do anyone know why hl=az not works? when hl=ru exists hl=az opens app store descriptions as hl=ru

Answer (score 3):

There is a Chrome extension for switching languages at Google Play.
[Play Store Language Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/play-store-language-switc/jcfdcbdcffghjnebhljdhopbbgmhohmo)

Comment: To me it seems, as if this chrome extension only adds the query parameter for the language to the URL. And I also think it is important to wait a few houres after publishing a new translation. And the query parameter has to be this form: hl=jp-JP or similar for other countries.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to do this:

> 1. You can just add ?hl= language parameter at the end of the url (see below). Or you can just click the link below:
>
> https://play.google.com/store?hl=en   (English)
> https://play.google.com/store?hl=th    (Thai)
>
> (Or)
>
> 2. Go to https://www.google.com/settings/personalinfo Then click at
>    "言語 (Language)" on the top center menu & then click at "日本語‬
>    (Japanese) in the box on the left" & then change to either "English"
>    or "ไทย"
>
> (Or)
>
> 3. You can download & install "Play Store Language Switcher"
>    extension on your Chrome browser.
>    https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/play-store-language-switc/jcfdcbdcffghjnebhljdhopbbgmhohmo

Source: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail-th/XGgW7GTLWLI

Answer (score 0):

You should change it in your Google+ profile.

Go to Google+ profile -> Click to your picture on top right. -> Account -> Language -> then change the language to the desired one. Check now Google Play.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

## Show language and / or rating

I have to add something because i've searched for the required parameters to show a specific language and / or a specific rating for that country.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?
id=[PACKAGE-NAME]&
hl=[LANGUAGE for the interface]&
gl=[REGION - Shows rating for the selected app]
```

**Example**

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twitter.android&hl=th&gl=th

## The Codes

###### List of supported language codes according to ISO 639-1

| LC | Country |
| --- | --- |
| af | Afghanistan |
| al | Albania |
| dz | Algeria |
| as | American Samoa |
| ad | Andorra |
| ao | Angola |
| ai | Anguilla |
| aq | Antarctica |
| ag | Antigua and Barbuda |
| ar | Argentina |
| am | Armenia |
| aw | Aruba |
| au | Australia |
| at | Austria |
| az | Azerbaijan |
| bs | Bahamas |
| bh | Bahrain |
| bd | Bangladesh |
| bb | Barbados |
| by | Belarus |
| be | Belgium |
| bz | Belize |
| bj | Benin |
| bm | Bermuda |
| bt | Bhutan |
| bo | Bolivia |
| ba | Bosnia and Herzegovina |
| bw | Botswana |
| bv | Bouvet Island |
| br | Brazil |
| io | British Indian Ocean Territory |
| bn | Brunei Darussalam |
| bg | Bulgaria |
| bf | Burkina Faso |
| bi | Burundi |
| kh | Cambodia |
| cm | Cameroon |
| ca | Canada |
| cv | Cape Verde |
| ky | Cayman Islands |
| cf | Central African Republic |
| td | Chad |
| cl | Chile |
| cn | China |
| cx | Christmas Island |
| cc | Cocos (Keeling) Islands |
| co | Colombia |
| km | Comoros |
| cg | Congo |
| cd | Congo, the Democratic Republic of the |
| ck | Cook Islands |
| cr | Costa Rica |
| ci | Cote D'ivoire |
| hr | Croatia |
| cu | Cuba |
| cy | Cyprus |
| cz | Czech Republic |
| dk | Denmark |
| dj | Djibouti |
| dm | Dominica |
| do | Dominican Republic |
| ec | Ecuador |
| eg | Egypt |
| sv | El Salvador |
| gq | Equatorial Guinea |
| er | Eritrea |
| ee | Estonia |
| et | Ethiopia |
| fk | Falkland Islands (Malvinas) |
| fo | Faroe Islands |
| fj | Fiji |
| fi | Finland |
| fr | France |
| gf | French Guiana |
| pf | French Polynesia |
| tf | French Southern Territories |
| ga | Gabon |
| gm | Gambia |
| ge | Georgia |
| de | Germany |
| gh | Ghana |
| gi | Gibraltar |
| gr | Greece |
| gl | Greenland |
| gd | Grenada |
| gp | Guadeloupe |
| gu | Guam |
| gt | Guatemala |
| gn | Guinea |
| gw | Guinea-Bissau |
| gy | Guyana |
| ht | Haiti |
| hm | Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands |
| va | Holy See (Vatican City State) |
| hn | Honduras |
| hk | Hong Kong |
| hu | Hungary |
| is | Iceland |
| in | India |
| id | Indonesia |
| ir | Iran, Islamic Republic of |
| iq | Iraq |
| ie | Ireland |
| il | Israel |
| it | Italy |
| jm | Jamaica |
| jp | Japan |
| jo | Jordan |
| kz | Kazakhstan |
| ke | Kenya |
| ki | Kiribati |
| kp | Korea, Democratic People's Republic of |
| kr | Korea, Republic of |
| kw | Kuwait |
| kg | Kyrgyzstan |
| la | Lao People's Democratic Republic |
| lv | Latvia |
| lb | Lebanon |
| ls | Lesotho |
| lr | Liberia |
| ly | Libyan Arab Jamahiriya |
| li | Liechtenstein |
| lt | Lithuania |
| lu | Luxembourg |
| mo | Macao |
| mk | Macedonia, the Former Yugosalv Republic of |
| mg | Madagascar |
| mw | Malawi |
| my | Malaysia |
| mv | Maldives |
| ml | Mali |
| mt | Malta |
| mh | Marshall Islands |
| mq | Martinique |
| mr | Mauritania |
| mu | Mauritius |
| yt | Mayotte |
| mx | Mexico |
| fm | Micronesia, Federated States of |
| md | Moldova, Republic of |
| mc | Monaco |
| mn | Mongolia |
| ms | Montserrat |
| ma | Morocco |
| mz | Mozambique |
| mm | Myanmar |
| na | Namibia |
| nr | Nauru |
| np | Nepal |
| nl | Netherlands |
| an | Netherlands Antilles |
| nc | New Caledonia |
| nz | New Zealand |
| ni | Nicaragua |
| ne | Niger |
| ng | Nigeria |
| nu | Niue |
| nf | Norfolk Island |
| mp | Northern Mariana Islands |
| no | Norway |
| om | Oman |
| pk | Pakistan |
| pw | Palau |
| ps | Palestinian Territory, Occupied |
| pa | Panama |
| pg | Papua New Guinea |
| py | Paraguay |
| pe | Peru |
| ph | Philippines |
| pn | Pitcairn |
| pl | Poland |
| pt | Portugal |
| pr | Puerto Rico |
| qa | Qatar |
| re | Reunion |
| ro | Romania |
| ru | Russian Federation |
| rw | Rwanda |
| sh | Saint Helena |
| kn | Saint Kitts and Nevis |
| lc | Saint Lucia |
| pm | Saint Pierre and Miquelon |
| vc | Saint Vincent and the Grenadines |
| ws | Samoa |
| sm | San Marino |
| st | Sao Tome and Principe |
| sa | Saudi Arabia |
| sn | Senegal |
| rs | Serbia and Montenegro |
| sc | Seychelles |
| sl | Sierra Leone |
| sg | Singapore |
| sk | Slovakia |
| si | Slovenia |
| sb | Solomon Islands |
| so | Somalia |
| za | South Africa |
| gs | South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands |
| es | Spain |
| lk | Sri Lanka |
| sd | Sudan |
| sr | Suriname |
| sj | Svalbard and Jan Mayen |
| sz | Swaziland |
| se | Sweden |
| ch | Switzerland |
| sy | Syrian Arab Republic |
| tw | Taiwan, Province of China |
| tj | Tajikistan |
| tz | Tanzania, United Republic of |
| th | Thailand |
| tl | Timor-Leste |
| tg | Togo |
| tk | Tokelau |
| to | Tonga |
| tt | Trinidad and Tobago |
| tn | Tunisia |
| tr | Turkey |
| tm | Turkmenistan |
| tc | Turks and Caicos Islands |
| tv | Tuvalu |
| ug | Uganda |
| ua | Ukraine |
| ae | United Arab Emirates |
| uk | United Kingdom |
| gb | United Kingdom |
| us | United States |
| um | United States Minor Outlying Islands |
| uy | Uruguay |
| uz | Uzbekistan |
| vu | Vanuatu |
| ve | Venezuela |
| vn | Viet Nam |
| vg | Virgin Islands, British |
| vi | Virgin Islands, U.S. |
| wf | Wallis and Futuna |
| eh | Western Sahara |
| ye | Yemen |
| zm | Zambia |
| zw | Zimbabwe |