# Google.Play web interface hl parameter for arabic language

Tags: android, localization, google-play

How to view Arabic app description page in Google.Play?
According to [How can I switch language in google play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592187/how-can-i-switch-language-in-google-play) you just need to add appropriate language code as a “hl” GET parameter to view Google.Play app description in different language.

Eg. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm&hl=zh for Chinese.
But this method is not working for Arabic, Hebrew and several other languages. Is there a way to view the app's details in this case?

Comment: it is working now: https://play.google.com/store?hl=ar

Answer (score 4):

This is the reply I got from Google Play Developer Support regarding RTL languages on November 21, 2014:

> Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support. Please note that
>   the Google Play Store doesn't currently support right-to-left
>   languages. Our product team is currently working to implement this
>   functionality, though I don't have an ETA I can provide at this time.
>   I apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> While we don't currently support the specific functionality you're
>   requesting, we place a high value on developer feedback. We'll pass
>   your feedback along to our product team for consideration.
>
> We're constantly releasing new features and functionality; Stay tuned,
>   and thanks for your patience as we work to improve Google Play.
>
> Regards, Google Play Developer Support

This explains why the `&hl` parameter does nothing for RTL language codes. Furthermore, adding an English localization to the store listing will force it to display in English by default, when the actual store listing's default language is an RTL language. Since we cannot use the `&hl` parameter to display the RTL language, it creates a problem for us middle-eastern folks who want to have both an English and RTL translation of the store listing. The English translation overrides the RTL by default.

Comment: I have been able to work around this by specifying the English translation under the "French" Play Store translation, and then linking to it using &hl=fr. The RTL language stays default.

Comment: It is 2015-10-11, and the problem persists. My app is in English and in Hebrew. When I set my phone to have Hebrew default language, google play shows the Hebrew translation, as expected. Web UI is broken, hl does not work. @Elad Nava, a nifty trick, but how would that look for french users?

Comment: Indeed, French users will see the English translation by default. You can provide the English translation under a different, less popular language, and then link to it via &hl={iso-language-code}.

Comment: Elad Nava, what bothers me in this approach is this. what you suggest works well on web. on mobile, however someone with English default will see hl=en equivalent, in Hebrew. someone with Hebrew will see hl=iw version, so it is ok, but for English default people it will look Hebrew. If she is a bi-lingual, that is fine, but for a global app, that wants to talk to people in their default language, it is a no-go. Seems there is no good solution short of Google fixing this problem. What I think of doing is publishing Hebrew as a separate app. It has a bunch of drawbacks too, so I am hesitant.

Comment: @Michael I think our best bet is to try to get Google to fix this silly bug. English translation should not be overriding RTL translation for users who's locale is RTL. Publishing 2 apps has lots of drawbacks as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Google Play has intentionally hidden the Arabic language on their web interface since recent UI update (as I remember in 4 ~5 months ago).

Though without official explanation about this change, it is suspected that their latest UI is not optimally fit into right-to-left layout and that's why they decided to hidden that language version.

Answer (score 0):

The Play Store recently got a redesign and seems to fully support Arabic now. For example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zhiliaoapp.musically&hl=ar.

[image]