# How can I switch my Google Play language to Arabic?

Tags: google-play

I switch languages by adding '&hl=' like this,
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.xxx&hl=en

but it doesn't work when I replace 'en' with 'ar',
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.xxx&hl=ar page is in English.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google.Play web interface hl parameter for arabic language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693254/google-play-web-interface-hl-parameter-for-arabic-language)